# Extracting unique value rows from a table into new data frame

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table (shown below) with different columns, such as ID, Target, dates. In my target column, i have some unique values with '>1','<=3'. I would like to extract those unique value rows into a new data frame.

I personally tried doing it manually by finding every unique value. However I am having difficulty putting that in new data frame. Furthermore my approach is not reliable as my original table is actually more than 200 rows.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Create sample dataframe
 raw_data = {'ID': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], 
'Domain': ['Finance', 'IT', 'IT', 'Finance'], 
'Target': [1, 2, '<=3', '>1'], 
"1/01":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1],
"1/02":[0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9], 
"1/03":[1, 1, 0.5, 1.1], 
"1/04":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1],
"1/05":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1], 
"1/06":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1]}


 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'Domain', 'Target', '1/01', 
'1/02','1/03', '1/04','1/05', '1/06'])
```

In the output I would have two dataframe where the first data frame will only contain rows which are not unique type and other data frame will have the unique values.

Comment: Can you explain further about the definition of _unique values_? Is it unique if it not purely digits?

Comment: Hello, In my case the unique value would be '<=3', '>1' or any null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `to_numeric`

```
yourdf=df[pd.to_numeric(df.Target,errors='coerce').isna()].copy()
Out[648]: 
   ID   Domain Target  1/01  1/02  1/03  1/04  1/05  1/06
2  C1       IT    <=3   2.1   0.5   0.5   0.1   0.1   2.1
3  D1  Finance     >1   1.0   0.9   1.1   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it did do the work. However, it did not remove those value from my df. I was wondering if its possible to remove it from my df.? Please.

Comment: `df=df[pd.to_numeric(df.Target,errors='coerce').notna()];`@krijan this is to remove them drom df

Comment: Thank you very much :) i really appreciate your help